# Change "copy of ..." when copying and pasting files in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, copy-paste

I have a file called "**text.txt**" and when copying and pasting into the finder a copy is created "**copy of text.txt**" is there any way to change this? that is, when copying and pasting is like this: "**text_1.txt**" or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What have you already tried to make this change?

Comment: @fsb Nothing really, I have 1 hour looking for some solution in Google, but I can not find anything, that's why I come here to look for help :)